# How to order a set of tasks where each has a starting cost and reward

Tags: algorithm

Assume you start with T amount of money, you want to find internships but because you have no experience you can't get into any, so you decided to buy into paid internships.

You are given a set of internships each with a buying cost C_b to get you in first, and once you are in you get paid back some money C_p. C_b can be either greater or smaller or the same than C_p so the net gain can be either positive or negative or 0.

Edit :The goal is to do all the internships.

Is there an algorithm to find out the order to do all the internships (in O(n^2))? And it can find out if there's no way to order e.g(The money left if not enough to buy you into any remaining internships). Thanks!

I'm really confused as to where to even start.

Comment: Is the goal to do as many internships as possible, because why would you buy into one that pays back less?

Comment: Yes the goal is to do all the internships if possible.

Comment: Do you want an implementation in code, if so what language?

Comment: I want like a paragraph describing how the algorithm works to find the order. Code is fine too if it's easier, any language is fine, python would be better if possible, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To restate the question: How can you find the most effective order to do buy-in internships in, that maximizes the number of internships you can do.

Given:

- A set of internships, each with a buy-in cost (`C_b`) and payback amount (`C_p`)
- `C_b` may be greater than or less than `C_p`
- You have some amount of `money` that cannot go into the negative

#### The Algorithm

1. Sort the internships by `net gain` in descending order
2. Loop through this sorted set of internships

   - If `money - C_b >= 0`
   - then do the internship and `money = money + net gain`
3. Repeat step 2, looping over the skipped internships, until you complete a loop without doing another internship.

With this algorithm you will do the internships that pay you the most first, which increases your ability to buy in to more internships.

**EDIT**

I believe a more efficient algorithm would be, upon finding a suitable internship at step 2, to start the loop back at from the beginning (in case you're now able to do one of the skipped higher net gain internships).

Comment: What if there's an internship where at the time you only have $45 left, the net gain of the next internship is $3 but the initial cost is $46? And the next internship with net gain of $2 has initial cost of $2, this mean you can have at least 1 more. Do you just skip it?

Comment: You are correct, our condition should actually just check the buy-in cost, not the net gain

Comment: I've updated my answer, though it may not be the most efficient with more thought.

Comment: I find out a sequence where the algorithm isn't optimal. For example you have $50, first internship (-41, +36)(net: -5) second (-25, +19)(net: -6), third (-40, +33)(net: -7). If it follows the algorithm by the time it finishes the second internship i will have $39 left and can't do the third one. But if i do the third one first i can do all three.

Comment: Yea..I think I'm gonna throw in the towel on this one, not sure how to get around that.